# CakePHP-2.0 and Migration plugin: How can i make id column auto_increment?

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, cakedc

```
https://github.com/CakeDC/users/blob/2.0/Config/Migration/001_initialize_users_schema.php#L49
```

How can i make the id  column auto_increment ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your users table to int, primary key, auto-increment.
If you are using the user_details, change the user_id to int too.